# Unable to connect via cx_Oracle using SessionPool with External + Proxy Authentication

Tags: python, proxy, kerberos, cx-oracle

Background:
I have a Kerberized Oracle DB that I am able to connect to using

```
pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(externalauth=True, dsn=dsn, threaded=True, homogeneous=False, encoding='UTF-8', nencoding='UTF-8')
conn = pool.acquire()
```

Currently, I want to connect using proxy connection as instructed in the [cx_Oracle docs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/7.2.3/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connecting-using-external-authentication). I'm able to do so in standalone connection but not in pooled connection:

```
# Standalone connection
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='[session_user]', dsn=dsn, encoding='UTF-8')
# Executing testing query below:
# PROXY_USER: my_user
# SESSION_USER: session_user

# Pooled connection
pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(externalauth=True, homogeneous=False, dsn=dsn, encoding='UTF-8')
conn = pool.acquire(user='[session_user]')  # shown as <cx_Oracle.Connection to user [session_user]@local> in debugger
# Executing testing query below:
# PROXY_USER: None
# SESSION_USER: my_user

# Testing query:
# SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'PROXY_USER'),
#        SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')
# FROM DUAL;
```

I've checked the %ORACLE_HOME% and %TNS_ADMIN% are pointing to the correct path. I'm wondering why did the acquired connection becomes @local and is this related to why the proxy connection failing.
Not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What behavior or error did you see?  What version Oracle Client libraries are you using?  There was a fix in Oracle Client 18.3.

For me, the code:

```
import cx_Oracle

print(cx_Oracle.clientversion())

pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(externalauth=True, dsn="localhost/orclpdb1", homogeneous=False)
conn = pool.acquire()

with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = """SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'PROXY_USER'),
       SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')
       FROM DUAL"""
    for r in cursor.execute(sql):
        print(r)

pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(externalauth=True, dsn="localhost/orclpdb1", homogeneous=False)
conn = pool.acquire(user='[mysessionuser2]')

with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = """SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'PROXY_USER'),
       SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')
       FROM DUAL"""
    for r in cursor.execute(sql):
        print(r)
```

gives:

```
[oracle@localhost j]$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/cjones/src/oracle/instantclient/instantclient12.2.0.1/instantclient_12_2-linux.x64
[oracle@localhost j]$ python prx.py 
(12, 2, 0, 1, 0)
(None, 'OPS$ORACLE')
(None, 'OPS$ORACLE')
[oracle@localhost j]$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/cjones/src/oracle/instantclient/instantclient19.6/instantclient_19_6-linux.x64/
[oracle@localhost j]$ python prx.py 
(19, 6, 0, 0, 0)
(None, 'OPS$ORACLE')
('OPS$ORACLE', 'MYSESSIONUSER2')
```